# How do I increase the padding on my pandas dataframe plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot some histogram using pandas. Here's some sample code that does something similar to what I'm doing:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000), index=pd.date_range('2018-10-14', periods=1000))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 6), index=ts.index, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
df = df.cumsum()
df.hist()
```

The data shows in a histogram fine, with one slight problem:

[image: six histograms with a D overlapping -20]

My histogram labels at the top overlap the X-axis labels at the bottom of the next row.

I would love to be able to add some spacing between these, but I haven't found any information about how to do this.

How can I increase the padding between my plots using pandas and matplotlib?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [subplots_adjust](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html) after your `df.hist()` call:

```
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As joe Specified you can specify `hspace` in your code, Moreover you can click on `configure subplots` button in after `plt.show()`. Modify `hspace` value in this scale dynamically.

Step-1

[image]

Step-2

[image]

Step-3

[image]